# Eclipse fails to check out my Eclipse project from git (Bitbucket) (missing main-method, JRA, build path-setting)

Tags: java, git, eclipse, bitbucket

I have read probably a dozen questions and answers here on SO about issues where Eclipse can't run a project because it can't see the main-method but none of the solutions have worked for me.

To start with, `Build Path` is missing. That is, if I right click on my project, the build path submenu just lists `No actions available` (and there is no Build Path section if I open the project's properties' window).

Background: I started a Java-project locally, without using Git. I changed my mind a couple of times where to store the project so I have moved it twice. After the first, but before the last, move I added the project to Bitbucket.

Somewhere along the way stuff broke but since I knew I had working copy at Bitbucket, I just deleted everything stored locally and checked out a fresh copy. But this doesn't work.

I have this hierarchy in Eclipse when looking in the Project Explorer:

```
projA
        A
        B
        C
```

In A-C I then have

```
A
    src
        A
            AMyMainClass.java
            SupportClass.java
```

Comments

- I am not sure if `A` ocurred twice like that in the project when it worked.
- I should have JRE at some level (probably next to `src`) in this hierarchy but it is missing
- When everything works as expected you should be able to "expand" the source files and see the methods. That is missing for me.
- The source files have the outline J symbol, rather than the correct, filled J:
  [image: outlined J java class]

However, on Bitbucket, it looks a bit different:

```
ARepo
    A
    B
    C
    .gitignore-default
    .project
```

As you can see the `projA` level is missing. Also, `.project` is quite empty, see the end of this post for its content (mostly `<name>proj></name>`).

A-C, in their turn,

```
A
    .settings/
    src/A/
    .classpath
    .gitignore
    .project
```

- The content of .classpath and .gitignore seems reasonable
- .project contains exactly the same as the file with the same name above (in the root of the repo)

Some final notes:

- While adding code, I got a couple of warnings about Eclipse not being able to save the workspace and/or project settings or similar. Don't remember the details but that is the reason for the second move of the workspace (I started by storing the workspace and projects locally, then moved it to a network volume, these warnings popped up so I therefore decided to move it back to the local harddrive).
- I have tried both the normal Git-import as well as the "smart import".

I am not really sure what to ask now, but:

**How do I make my project work again? Why is the JRE missing? Why is the build path option missing? Anything else?**

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>projA</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: That .project file contents shows the project is not a Java project which is why the JRE and Build Path are missing (there would be entries in the `buildSpec` and `natures` if it was Java).

Comment: @greg-449 So how do I convert it to a Java project? And why did it change from a Java project to some kind of generic type?